# I can’t find my plane I bought in my hanger (GTA V Story Mode)

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I have recently purchased the Besra in GTA story mode playing as Michael but it does not appear in my hanger and have ended up buying it twice now!! I would also like to ask if once your plane has been destroyed is it still accessible in your hanger?

Answer (score 4):

Your plane ([Besra](http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/Besra)) should be in the airfield that you own, there is a glitch that sometimes sends the plane to [Sands Shores Airfield](http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/Sandy_Shores_Airfield). You might even find both of your planes there. Other players have also said that sometimes it takes 10 minutes to 3 hours for your plane to "arrive" almost all players says that their planes eventually arrived (or they stumbled on it at the sandy shores one) All I can say is just be patient and it should come... eventually. If the plane that you **bought crashes, it will end up in the airfield it arrived in.**

Answer (score 3):

If it will not show up in the hangar, just go inside it and press E (pc). Then a list of purchased aircrafts will show. Simply select and confirm .... There you go.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I checked all 3 hangers and the newly purchased plane wasn't there. You actually have to go INSIDE the hangar to trigger a prompt that lets you select the plane you want to have in hangar storage. Your purchased plane should show up there.